# How to prove distributivity (propositional validity property 6) in LEAN?

Tags: functional-programming, theorem-proving, lean

Having gone through most exercises and also solved/proved in LEAN the first five propositional validities/properties at the end of chapter 3 in the LEAN manual, I still have trouble with the following implication (one of the implications needed for the proof of property 6):

```
theorem Distr_or_L (p q r : Prop) : (p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ r) → p ∨ (q ∧ r) :=
begin
    intros pqpr, 
    have porq : p ∨ q, from pqpr.left,
    have porr : p ∨ r, from pqpr.right,
    sorry
end
```

The difficulty I face is mainly due to the case when `p` is not true, as I don't know how to combine, using LEAN tools, the two sides of the `and` in the hypothesis to obtain the fact that both `q` and `r` must hold under that scenario. I would greatly appreciate any help here; please help me understand how to construct this proof in the above setting without importing any other tactics except those in standard LEAN. For completeness, here is my proof of the other direction:

```
theorem Distr_or_R (p q r : Prop) : p ∨ (q ∧ r) → (p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ r) :=
begin
    intros pqr,
    exact or.elim pqr 
    ( assume hp: p, show (p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ r), from 
        and.intro (or.intro_left q hp) (or.intro_left r hp) ) 
    ( assume hqr : (q ∧ r), show (p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ r), from 
        and.intro (or.intro_right p hqr.left) (or.intro_right p hqr.right) ) 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Try case splitting on both `porq` and `porr`.

Here's a solution

```
theorem Distr_or_L (p q r : Prop) : (p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ r) → p ∨ (q ∧ r) :=
begin
    intros pqpr, 
    have porq : p ∨ q, from pqpr.left,
    have porr : p ∨ r, from pqpr.right,
    { cases porq with hp hq,
      { exact or.inl hp },
      { cases porr with hp hr,
        { exact or.inl hp },
        { exact or.inr ⟨hq, hr⟩ } } }
end
```

Comment: This works great. For most people, myself included, the problem may be that `cases` is not yet introduced or used in any example by the time this is encountered in chapter 3. Unless, of course, it was and I just didn't notice - always a possibility!

Comment: Is this a proper use of `cases`? I seem to bump into some problem again, as my `hyp` would need to be rewritten to work for `not p`. How can this be completed? ```theorem T11 : ¬(p → ¬p) := 
begin
    assume hyp : p → ¬ p,
    cases (em p) with hp hnp,
    exact (hyp hp) hp,
    exact sorry
end```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an asnwer for say problem without using cases. (explained later in tbe mentioned book)

```
example : p ∨ (q ∧ r) ↔ (p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ r) :=
Iff.intro
 (fun hpqr => Or.elim hpqr
 (fun hp: p => 
 show (p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ r) from And.intro (Or.inl hp) (Or.inl hp))
 (fun hqr: q ∧ r => 
 show (p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ r) from And.intro (Or.inr hqr.left) (Or.inr hqr.right)))
(fun hpqpr: (p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ r) => 
 have hpq: (p ∨ q) := hpqpr.left;
 have hpr: (p ∨ r) := hpqpr.right;
   Or.elim hpq
    (fun hp: p => show p ∨ (q ∧ r) from Or.inl hp)
    (fun hq: q => Or.elim hpr 
       (fun hp: p => show p ∨ (q ∧ r) from Or.inl hp)
       (fun hr: r => show p ∨ (q ∧ r) from Or.inr (And.intro hq hr))))
```

You're using the information in the right part of the conjunction, otherwise, the left part doesn't give any info regarding r.